# Partial Page Rendering on SelectedNodeChanged of tree view from MasterPage

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hi I am working on a website in which i need to access certain content pages from a treeview placed in a master page. When I am using `Response.Redirect` on the `SelectedNodeChanged` event of the tree view the entire page postbacks instead of the UpdatePanel(of the content page).Am i missing something or is this the expected behaviour.Also is there a work around for this?Please help

Answer (score 0):

I believe Response.Redirect will always refresh the whole page, this is an Update Panel not an iframe. Why not place an iframe into the page, into an Update Panel. OnClick of the tree, set the src of iframe to what you want, then call UpdatePanel.Update()...